# Having trouble with Symfony2 uploading file from external program - 'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream'

Tags: symfony, post, symfony-2.8

I have a Symfony2 endpoint that needs to accept a post request with a few text parameters and a zip file delivered by a 3rd party program. For quick development I started out by just using a Chrome POST plugin to spoof sending the form data. I was able to retrieve the file just fine when using that method.

However, when I switched to the 3rd party Windows application for uploading reports, I'm no longer able to retrieve the file. Instead of figuring out that it's a zip file, I now get `mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream'`, and the file size is 0.

I read here in the following link that I needed to make sure my post_max_size and upload_max_filesize were large enough to handle the file. [Can't upload image with mime-type "application/octet-stream" in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268058/cant-upload-image-with-mime-type-application-octet-stream-in-symfony2)

I didn't want to mess around, so I set it to 100mb, but still no luck.

Here is a dump of the Request:

```
[2016-08-24 10:15:48] app.INFO: Request dump: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::__set_state(array(    'attributes' =>    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::__set_state(array(      'parameters' =>      array (       '_format' => 'xml',       '_controller' => 'Company\\Bundle\\CompanyBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::cloudTransferReport',       '_route' => 'hg_cloudtransfer_report',       '_route_params' =>        array (         '_format' => 'xml',       ),       '_method' =>        Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method::__set_state(array(          'methods' =>          array (           0 => 'POST',           1 => 'GET',         ),       )),     ),   )),    'request' =>    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::__set_state(array(      'parameters' =>      array (       'submitter' => 'hgis',       'version' => '5.1.26.0',       'userName' => 'admin',       'password' => 'kitten',     ),   )),    'query' =>    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::__set_state(array(      'parameters' =>      array (     ),   )),    'server' =>    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag::__set_state(array(      'parameters' =>      array (       'REDIRECT_HTTPS' => 'on',       'REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI' => 'example.com',       'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',       'HTTPS' => 'on',       'SSL_TLS_SNI' => 'example.com',       'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'multipart/form-data, boundary=AaBbCcDdHhGg40',       'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Some software v 5.1.26.0',       'HTTP_HOST' => 'example.com',       'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '3592731',       'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'no-cache',       'PATH' => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin',       'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '',       'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/5.5.36 LibreSSL/2.2.7',       'SERVER_NAME' => 'example.com',       'SERVER_ADDR' => '192.168.1.100',       'SERVER_PORT' => '443',       'REMOTE_ADDR' => '192.168.1.223',       'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/Users/user/Documents/symphony/cpsrecall/web',       'REQUEST_SCHEME' => 'https',       'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => '',       'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/Users/user/Documents/symphony/cpsrecall/web',       'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'chris@yourcontactpoint.com',       'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/Users/user/Documents/symphony/cpsrecall/web/app.php',       'REMOTE_PORT' => '51248',       'REDIRECT_URL' => '/hg/cloudtransfer/upload-report',       'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',       'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',       'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST',       'QUERY_STRING' => '',       'REQUEST_URI' => '/hg/cloudtransfer/upload-report',       'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/app.php',       'PHP_SELF' => '/app.php',       'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1472055346.6129999,       'REQUEST_TIME' => 1472055346,     ),   )),    'files' =>    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag::__set_state(array(      'parameters' =>      array (       'file1' =>        Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(          'test' => false,          'originalName' => '00000003-1.zip',          'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',          'size' => 0,          'error' => 1,       )),     ),   )),    'cookies' =>    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::__set_state(array(      'parameters' =>      array (     ),   )),    'headers' =>    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag::__set_state(array(      'headers' =>      array (       'content-type' =>        array (         0 => 'multipart/form-data, boundary=AaBbCcDdHhGg40',       ),       'user-agent' =>        array (         0 => 'Some software v 5.1.26.0',       ),       'host' =>        array (         0 => 'example.com',       ),       'content-length' =>        array (         0 => '3592731',       ),       'cache-control' =>        array (         0 => 'no-cache',       ),       'x-php-ob-level' =>        array (         0 => 1,       ),     ),      'cacheControl' =>      array (       'no-cache' => true,     ),   )),    'content' => '',    'languages' => NULL,    'charsets' => NULL,    'encodings' => NULL,    'acceptableContentTypes' => NULL,    'pathInfo' => '/hg/cloudtransfer/upload-report',    'requestUri' => '/hg/cloudtransfer/upload-report',    'baseUrl' => '',    'basePath' => NULL,    'method' => 'POST',    'format' => NULL,    'session' =>    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session::__set_state(array(      'storage' =>      Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage::__set_state(array(        'bags' =>        array (         'attributes' =>          Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag::__set_state(array(            'name' => 'attributes',            'storageKey' => '_sf2_attributes',            'attributes' =>            array (           ),         )),         'flashes' =>          Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag::__set_state(array(            'name' => 'flashes',            'flashes' =>            array (           ),            'storageKey' => '_sf2_flashes',         )),       ),        'started' => false,        'closed' => false,        'saveHandler' =>        Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy::__set_state(array(          'handler' =>          SessionHandler::__set_state(array(         )),          'wrapper' => true,          'active' => false,          'saveHandlerName' => 'files',       )),        'metadataBag' =>        Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag::__set_state(array(          'name' => '__metadata',          'storageKey' => '_sf2_meta',          'meta' =>          array (           'c' => 0,           'u' => 0,           'l' => 0,         ),          'lastUsed' => NULL,          'updateThreshold' => '0',       )),     )),      'flashName' => 'flashes',      'attributeName' => 'attributes',   )),    'locale' => NULL,    'defaultLocale' => 'en', )) [] []
```

and for those who don't want to read that big long line, here's just the FileBag:

```
[2016-08-24 10:15:48] app.INFO: file1dump: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(    'test' => false,    'originalName' => '00000003-1.zip',    'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',    'size' => 0,    'error' => 1, )) [] []
```

Here is my code up that should grab the file, but perhaps I'm going about it wrong:

```
public function cloudTransferReport(Request $request)
{
    $logger = $this->get('logger');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $data = $request->request;
    $files = $request->files;

    $submitter = $data->get('submitter');
    $version = $data->get('version');
    $memberName = $data->get('userName');
    $password = $data->get('password');
    $file1 = $files->get('file1');

    $logger->info("file string: " . var_export($stuff, true));
    $logger->info("file1dump: " . var_export($file1, true));
```

If you need more code from that controller let me know, but I thought I should at least be able to have the file in memory at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Mac users who run into an issue like this, especially those who have used homebrew, and may or may not have more than one version of PHP installed.

You may have more than one php.ini file on your computer. I ran the `php --ini`, and it came up with `Loaded Configuration File: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini`. IT WAS WRONG!

Ends up the real php.ini file that Apache was using was in `/etc/php.ini`, so please, please, please don't waste a whole day banging your head against the keyboard. Make sure you're in the file that Apache is actually using! That is all. I'm going to crawl under my desk and cry now.